# Add version number to Data Explorer's footer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

[Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) should have a visible version number somewhere, like SO has right corner of the footer (revision: 2010.6.8.1).

This way we'll know when version change and can refer to specific versions in bug reports etc.

Comment: I agree ... need to set up some way for doing this in a post build step

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it took us a while to get there, but you can now see the build/version number of SEDE in the footer, exactly like it works on the core sites.

[image: version in footer]